# How access bool from other form/script?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean

How can I access a bool from another form in c# ?
e.g. I want access public bool isTrue = true; from Form1 in Form2.
How to do this ?

I only know how to do this in Unity3D Form1.isTrue = true; but this doesn't work in C# with .Net Forms ....

Comment: I guess you are talking about WinForms. Are you creating an instance of form2 in form1?

Comment: Form1.isTrue = true; will work if it is static `public static bool isTrue = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick and dirty approach just declare it as static.

```
public static bool isTrue = true;
```

then you can access it with Form1.isTrue = true;

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to approach this. 
I'd suggest creating a class to hold your various shared state, including your bool, and then constructing both Forms passing in this state object. 
Or at a minimum, using a constructor for Form2 which passes in the state.

Comment: Currently I've only a public bool isTrue = true; in my Form1 script.

Comment: I wanna do this as easy as possible :)
I hope this works like in Unity3D with accessing bools from another script :)